# HTML ImageSlider Media Query adaption

Tags: html, media-queries, slideshow

Hey i have made a media query:
Now i want to change the "@keyframes slide" code for media query (for devices with 600px or less) but it wont apply in my media query can anyone tell me how to alter keyframes in media query so i can make the Slideshow smaller  ty